# <input type="file" multiple="multiple" /> does not allow to select multiple files

Tags: html, jsp, browser, file-upload

I am witing a JSP to upload multiple files to server at one go. Many tutorials mention to use property "multiple" to achieve this. 
e.g.

```
<input type="file"  name="myFiles" multiple="multiple" />
```

However when I deploy web application and access this JSP; the window explorer popup (which appears on clicking on "browse" does not allow me to select more than one file. 
Even by pressing control or by mouse dragging; multiple files can not be selected.

Are there any more steps/settings to achieve this ?

Comment: What browser are you using? See browser support table here - http://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_input_multiple.asp Most significant is IE10+ support. By the way in Chrome 43 it works fine: http://jsfiddle.net/Lt4efg5b/

Comment: What version of IE and is the IE running in a different mode?

Comment: I am using Mozilla Firefox 38.1

Answer (score 1):

use 'multiple' as attribute, not like property, I guess?

```
<input type="file" name="myFiles" multiple>
```

Answer (score 0):

I think there's an option to set the name to `name="myFiles[]"`, then you get it from an array;

```
myFiles[1], myFiles[2], myFiles[3], ect...
```

I do believe you can read arrays in JSP, never used the language myself though.